# PHP / MySQL extracting specific piece of text in a string

Tags: php, mysql, preg-match

Could some helpful fellow please advise me how to extract a specific part of a string? They usually look like this:

```
Includes USD39 bundled airtime, 30 SMSs and 50MB data.
Includes USD200 bundled airtime, 110 SMSs and 450MB data.
Includes USD399 bundled airtime, 500 SMSs and 650MB data.
```

All I would like to to is display the

```
USD39 bundled airtime 
USD200 bundled airtime
USD399 bundled airtime
```

pieces from each string.

I know this will be painfully easy for pretty much anyone here, so apologies :D hopefully I can ask a more challenging question one day..

Comment: Could you post what you have tried?

Comment: try preg_replace("/Includes (.*),.*/", "$1", $str);

Comment: Why is this question beeing downvoted?

Comment: @2cent maybe because the OP doesn't show what he has already tried (if ever he tried something). SO is not a "code this for me please" website.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions rocks!

```
$str = 'Includes USD39 bundled airtime, 30 SMSs and 50MB data.';
$matches = array();
preg_match('/ USD\d+ bundled airtime/i', $str, $matches);
echo '<pre>', print_r($matches, 1), '</pre>';

// more complex:
$matches = array();
preg_match('/ (USD\d+ [^,]+),/i', $str, $matches);
echo '<pre>', print_r($matches, 1), '</pre>';

// another way:
$matches = array();
preg_match('/^Includes ([^,]+),/i', $str, $matches);
echo '<pre>', print_r($matches, 1), '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(sentence,LOCATE(' ',sentence),LOCATE(' ',sentence,(LOCATE(' ',sentence)+1))-LOCATE(' ',sentence))
```

FROM (SELECT 'Includes USD39 bundled airtime, 30 SMSs and 50MB data' AS sentence) temp

This should extract USD39, however its not checked. hope this works to get the different USD values for you as third and fourth values are same in each statement.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: It would be better to keep the logic inside the PHP code instead of the Mysql query itself.

Answer (score -1):

Try doing this

```
echo substr("Hello world",1,8);
```

Similarly formulate your answer. (This is a php function. Hope it helps.) Otherwise regular expression will be the key.

Comment: This is not what the OP wants.